# Take input from the keyboard using a loop till the time the user presses 0 and print their average value on the screen

Tags: python

What this is supposed to do is:
To ask the user for numbers using while loop until they enter 0
when 0 is pressed we need to print the average of the numbers entered so far.
(Kindly help)

Comment: https://www.codesdope.com/discussion/take-integer-inputs-from-user-until-heshe-presses-/

Comment: You can find many

Comment: @badhushamuhammed Oh, well I have tried that, But, It didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As it is now, you are not asking a question on a particular bit which doesn't work as expected/you don't understand, but are asking for the whole code for a program.

Comment: @Badda I have got the answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take each number and print the average so far and stop it when input is zero, right?

```
s = 0
count = 0

while True:
    num = int(input('Write a number: '))
    if num == 0:
        break
    s += num
    count += 1
    print("Average so far:",(s/count))
```

Could you add a piece of code you have tried or sample input and output too?

Answer (score 3):

```
import statistics as st

provided_numbers = []
while True:
    number = int(input('Write a number'))

    if number == 0:
       break
    else:
        provided_numbers.append(number)

print(f'Typed numbers: {provided_numbers}')
print(f'The average of the provided numbers is {st.mean(provided_numbers)}')
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for answering but It has to print the average of numbers printed so far as well.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. What I would do is to add a typed number to the list and then I would use a statistics module to compute the average